# how to setup voice chat over wifi and 3G network?

Tags: iphone, audio, sdk, voip

I wanted to add a voice chat feature to my business app. I have been trying hard to find anything useful but there is not much help regarding this. Could anyone plz point me to something concrete??

PS: The skype app makes use of this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a lot of work as there is no "built in" sdk features or third party off the self components that will help you do it without a lot of work on your end.
Your options (as far as I know) are:

- Build your own solution.
- Look for a third party solution.
- Look for a open source solution.

Voice "chat" could be one of many things like:

- using the voice features of a cellular network to a conference call.
- using the voice features of a cellular network with a PBX server that supports conference calls.
- using a [VOIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_Internet_Protocol) solution using a [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) stack with a SIP server
- using a [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) [Jingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29) solution (I believe the google voice service uses this)
- using your own SIP setup solution
- custom solution

None of these options are easy.

Open Source SIP implementations that have iphone ports (that I know of):

- [reSIProcate](http://www.resiprocate.org/Main_Page)
- [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/)

Update:

SIP & Jingle both use [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) for the actual  transport protocol between the parties.  RTP is a UDP point-to-point protocol. The ports which form a session are negotiated using other protocols such as RTSP (using SDP in the setup method) and SIP. RTP and RTCP typically use unprivileged UDP ports (1024 to 65535).

Comment: hey shane. Thanks & 1up for the information. I dint know abt the Opensource implementations(reSIProvate & pjsip). Will Look into it. PBX wont help me i guess. But i want something on the lines of Jingle. As of now all of these are too complicated for me.

Comment: hey do u know if we can make use of ports for p2p connections?

Comment: Added p2p info. as per the update, the RTP port is normally setup as per the overarching protocol.  So it can be anything including multicast ports.

Answer (score 1):

For easy Server / Client setup check [Jingle Nodes](http://jinglenodes.org) in combination with SIP Communicator which is a Desktop application. But as being opensource I presume you can reuse a lot of the code to make it mobile. Specially for Android. Check this draft of a [Jingle Nodes Setup Guide](https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AYRjaHIDbVEcZG52cmd3N180NzVrc201Z2JmYw&hl=en)